# Calling named query with `in()`, in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my Hibernate namedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getLanguagesForIds", query = "select l from Language l where l.languageId in(:ids)")
```

When I tried to execute the query, Hibernate is throwing exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I am passing the language ids as comma separated, like 1,2. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: A. it's supposed to be `in :ids`, and ids is supposed to be a Collection<Integer>, not a comma-separated String.

Comment: so I have to split the string and cast the string into numbers and then add to a collection and then pass it to the query, right?

Comment: Yes, except casting a String to an Integer will always fail, since a String is not an Integer. You need to *parse* the String.

Comment: yes `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use List = new ArrayList to hold the ids and pass that as parameter value rather than comma separated string.